# error running `sqlplus` as user `oracle`

Tags: linux, oracle

Im trying to run `sqlplus` from user `oracle` in linux, but i only get the following error.

`Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
 SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
 SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
 [ sqlplus ] completed with error code: 1`

I have tried to run `./oracle_env.sh` as user `oracle` and have tried it as user `root` as-well, but when I run the `sqlplus / as sysdba` command logged in as user `oracle` I get the above message.

Did I miss something, am I on completely the wrong track?

Here is a full output that I used/got.

```
`su - oracle  
 cd /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin
 ./oracle_env.sh
 sqlplus / as sysdba`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/oracle_env.sh` sets your `ORACLE_HOME`, and `ORACLE_SID` environment variables, you need to "source" it invoking it in the current environment) using the "dot" prefix:

```
. ./oracle_env.sh
```

In any case, looks like your environment variables (including `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) may not be set correctly.

Comment: Thanks Mark. So learning that the `. `  prefix is the kind of include statement, it makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: Yes, if you invoke it that way, the statements in the script apply to the current environment; the way you had it, `oracle_env.sh` was launched in a new process, inheriting the existing environment, and then when it quit, any environment setup it did disappears along with the process!